# How to generate only one answer in huggingfacepipeline?

Tags: pytorch, langchain, large-language-model, huggingface, solar

When I ask a question through the HuggingFace pipeline and langchain, I want only one answer, but it keeps generating multiple questions and answers automatically. Is there a solution?

This is pipeline code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZaJk.png)

This is langchain Base code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRlHD.png)

This is answering image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHOiM.png)

I try to change huggingface parameter